# Specify the right time to call a function inside a setInterval

Tags: javascript, animation, frontend

I am trying to write a loop that switches from red, green and blue, but when it reaches the 255 of a color, it turn black.

I got stuck at the function change(), how can I specify to the function the exact time that it should call the inner functions (turnRed, turnGreen, turnBlue)?

```js
var r = 0;
var g = 0;
var b = 0;
var dir = true;

function turnRed(){
  if (dir == true){
    r < 256 ? r++ : 0;
    if (r == 255){
      dir = false;
    }else{
      turnBlack;
    }
  }
}

function turnGreen(){
  if (dir == true){
    g < 256 ? g++ : 0;
    if (g == 255){
      dir = false;
    }else{
      turnBlack;
    }
  }
}

function turnBlue(){
  if (dir == true){
    b < 256 ? b++ : 0;
    if (b == 255){
      dir = false;
    } else{
      turnBlack;
    }
  }
}

function turnBlack(){
  b > 0 ? b-- : 0;
  if (b == 0){
    dir = true;
  }

  g > 0 ? g-- : 0;
    if (g == 0){
      dir = true;
    }

  r > 0 ? r-- : 0;
    if (r == 0){
      dir = true;
   }
}

function change() {
    color = 'rgb('+r+', '+g+', '+b+')';
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = color;
    
    setTimeout(turnRed, 1000);
    clearInterval();
    //then
    setTimeout(turnGreen, 1000);
    clearInterval();
    //then
    setTimeout(turnBlue, 1000);
    clearInterval();
}

setInterval(change, 10);
clearInterval();
```

My logic: if I put setTimeout(function, time) into a setInterval, it will call the function once, and setInterval will run in a loop changing the colors, but in my case the function just runs once and stops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working example. There were a few bugs in your code. You didn't have the `()` after `turnBlack` to actually call the function. I removed the `g > 0 ? g-- : 0;` since you change direction when it's needed and then it won't matter. I'm also not sure the setTimeouts are needed inside change. This just delays everything 1 second from happening.

```js
var r = 0;
var g = 0;
var b = 0;
var dir = true;

function turnRed(){
  if (dir == true) {
    if (r < 256) { 
      r++;
    } else {
      dir = false;
    }
  } else {
    turnBlack();
  }
}



function turnGreen(){
  if (dir == true) {
    if (g < 256) { 
      g++;
    } else {
      dir = false;
    }
  } else {
    turnBlack();
  }
}


function turnBlue(){
  if (dir == true) {
    if (b < 256) { 
      b++;
    } else {
      dir = false;
    }
  } else {
    turnBlack();
  }
}


function turnBlack(){
  if (b == 0){
    dir = true;
  } else {
    b--
  }

    if (g == 0){
      dir = true;
    } else {
      g--
    }


    if (r == 0){
      dir = true;
   } else {
    r--
  }

}

function change() {
    color = 'rgb('+r+', '+g+', '+b+')';
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = color;
    
    setTimeout(turnRed, 1000);
    clearInterval();
    setTimeout(turnBlue, 1000);
    clearInterval();
    setTimeout(turnGreen, 1000);
    clearInterval();

}

setInterval(change, 10);
clearInterval();
```

Clear interval doesn't do anything unless you pass it an interval. But that would stop what you want. For example:

```
var myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 1000);
clearInterval(myVar)
```

I think this will work fine.

```js
var r = 0;
var g = 0;
var b = 0;
var dir = true;

function turnRed(){
  if (dir == true) {
    if (r < 256) { 
      r++;
    } else {
      dir = false;
    }
  } else {
    turnBlack();
  }
}



function turnGreen(){
  if (dir == true) {
    if (g < 256) { 
      g++;
    } else {
      dir = false;
    }
  } else {
    turnBlack();
  }
}


function turnBlue(){
  if (dir == true) {
    if (b < 256) { 
      b++;
    } else {
      dir = false;
    }
  } else {
    turnBlack();
  }
}


function turnBlack(){
  if (b == 0){
    dir = true;
  } else {
    b--
  }

    if (g == 0){
      dir = true;
    } else {
      g--
    }


    if (r == 0){
      dir = true;
   } else {
    r--
  }

}

function change() {
    color = 'rgb('+r+', '+g+', '+b+')';
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = color;
    
    turnRed();
    turnBlue();
    turnGreen();

}

setInterval(change, 10);
```

This changes colors individually. First to Red -> Black -> Green -> Black -> Blue -> Black

```js
var r = 0;
var g = 0;
var b = 0;
var dir = 'red';
var nextColor = 'green'

function turnRed(){
  if (dir == 'red') {
    if (r < 256) { 
      r++;
    } else {
      dir = 'black';
      nextColor = 'green'
    }
  }
}



function turnGreen(){
  if (dir == 'green') {
    if (g < 256) { 
      g++;
    } else {
      dir = 'black';
      nextColor = 'blue'
    }
  }
}


function turnBlue(){
  if (dir == 'blue') {
    if (b < 256) { 
      b++;
    } else {
      dir = 'black';
      nextColor='red';
    }
  }
}


function turnBlack(){
  if (dir !== 'black') return;

  if (b > 0) b--;
  if (r > 0) r--;
  if (g > 0) g--;

  if (b <= 0 && r <= 0 && g <= 0) {
    dir = nextColor;
  }
}

function change() {
    color = 'rgb('+r+', '+g+', '+b+')';
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = color;
    
    turnRed();
    turnBlue();
    turnGreen();
    turnBlack()
}

setInterval(change, 10);
```

Lastly this changes to Red, then decreases Red as it Increases Blue, and keeps doing that for all the colors.

```js
var r = 0;
var g = 0;
var b = 0;
var dir = 'red';
var nextColor = 'green'

function turnRed(){
  if (dir == 'red') {
    if (r < 256) { 
      r++;
    } else {
      dir = 'green'
    }
  }
}



function turnGreen(){
  if (dir == 'green') {
    if (g < 256) { 
      g++;
    } else {
      dir = 'blue'
    }
  }
}


function turnBlue(){
  if (dir == 'blue') {
    if (b < 256) { 
      b++;
    } else {
      dir = 'red';
    }
  }
}


function turnBlack(){
  if (b > 0 && dir !== 'blue') b--;
  if (r > 0 && dir !== 'red') r--;
  if (g > 0 && dir !== 'green') g--;
}

function change() {
    color = 'rgb('+r+', '+g+', '+b+')';
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = color;
    
    turnRed();
    turnBlue();
    turnGreen();
    turnBlack();
}

setInterval(change, 10);
```

Comment: What do you want then? They go from black to white and back to black. Or do you want it to go Red -> Black -> Green -> Black -> Blue -> Black?

Comment: Here is a 3rd demo - Goes through the order above. Ah I thought that was the OP, it was the other answerer. And a 4th that decreases one color as it increases the other.

Comment: Thank you Diesel, the third one was exactly what I was looking for! ;)

Comment: Perfect. Added a 4th too that doesn't go fully black - increases one color as it decreases another. Glad it helped!

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would go about it rather than trying to time intervals within a main loop.

`intervals` and `timeouts` are fine however for smooth transitions it's better to use [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame). In addition the way I set the code up is just a simple `cycle` function and you just iterate through the color patterns over time using the steps array.

Another note defintely check out [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) they're handy for things like this `` document.body.style.backgroundColor = `rgb(${red},${green},${blue})`; ``

```js
function cycle(val, target, step = 1) {
  if (val !== target) {
    return val += step;
  }

  return val;
}

const steps = [
  {r: 255, g: 0, b: 0},
  { r: 0, g: 0, b: 255},
  { r: 0 ,g: 255, b: 0},
  { r: 0, g: 0, b: 0 }
]

let curStep = 0;
let red = 0;
let green = 0;
let blue = 0;

function colorize() {
  requestAnimationFrame(colorize);
  const step = steps[curStep];
  const {r, g, b} = step;

  if (red === r && g === green && b === blue) {
    curStep++;
    if (curStep >= steps.length) {
      curStep = 0;
    }
  } else {
    red = cycle(red, r, r < red ? -1 : 1);
    green = cycle(green, g, g < green ? -1 : 1);
    blue = cycle(blue, b, b < blue ? -1 : 1);
  }
  
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = `rgb(${red},${green},${blue})`;
}

colorize();
```

If you wanted to actually time each color cycle you could do it this way outside of the main loop in the next example.

All this does is increase the current active step each time `setTimeout` is called, which in this example is 1, 5, and 8 seconds.

Note it wont continue after the last step since each one is scheduled in this example. The main method stays the same though, letting a function with `requestAnimationFrame` actually handle the updates.

```js
function cycle(val, target, step = 1) {
  if (val !== target) {
    return val += step;
  }

  return val;
}

const steps = [
  { r: 0, g: 0, b: 0 },
    {r: 255, g: 0, b: 0},
  { r: 0, g: 0, b: 255},
  { r: 0 ,g: 255, b: 0},
]

let curStep = 0;
let red = 0;
let green = 0;
let blue = 0;

function colorize() {
  requestAnimationFrame(colorize);
  const step = steps[curStep];
  const {r, g, b} = step;

  red = cycle(red, r, r < red ? -1 : 1);
  green = cycle(green, g, g < green ? -1 : 1);
  blue = cycle(blue, b, b < blue ? -1 : 1);
 
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = `rgb(${red},${green},${blue})`;
}


function nextStep() {
  curStep++;
  if (curStep >= steps.length) {
     curStep = 0;
  }
}

setTimeout(() => {nextStep()}, 1000);
setTimeout(() => {nextStep()}, 5000);
setTimeout(() => {nextStep()}, 8000);

colorize();
```